# Wifi access point without infrastructure

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wireless-adapter

I need to be able to connect a number of wifi devices to a laptop without proper infrastructure; specifically this is my use case...

I have a number of devices that utilize wifi, I have a laptop with my application running. I need to have connectivity between the laptop and the wifi devices. The environment that this runs in means there will not be proper wifi infrastructure.

So I need a method that will connect to my laptop via USB, CardBus or express card (i.e get power from the laptop) that will provide an access point for my devices to connect to. My devices do not support being connected to an ad hoc wifi network, so it needs to be a 'proper' access point. Also the laptop should then be able to be connected to the network through the medium that powers the device, USB for example.

I have found [this device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008BZAZL0) so far.

The problem is I can't figure out if my laptop would have to use its internal wifi to connect to the USB access point or if the connection can be through the USB.

I am not sure if such a product exists or not. Does such a product exist? I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a RT5370 based usb wifi NIC to host a Soft AP. That will still provide you with network connectivity through the NIC, as well as allow other devices to connect to your laptop via the Soft AP.

I've used the generic ebay RT5370s with great success in this area.
http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/RT5370-Mini-150Mbps-USB-Wireless-Network-Card-WiFi-LAN-Adapter-Antenna-/281205282525?pt=AU_Components&hash=item41792416dd  <-- that one comes with windows drivers to allow you to start using the AP fairly easily.

Comment: This looks interesting, when you say, "That will still provide you with network connectivity through the NIC, as well as allow other devices to connect to your laptop via the Soft AP.", does that mean my laptop will get a valid IP from the Soft AP also? This would be perfect, I don't need internet access, just infrastructure-less wifi network.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-Wireless-150Mbps-USB-Wifi-Adapter-802-11-w-Ralink-RT5370-Chip-and-Antenna-/350790344105) item look like it has the same features as the one you posted? The one you posted doesn't seem to ship to the US.

Comment: Your laptop will have a Static IP set, and yes the one you posted has the same features

Answer (score 0):

The USB port on the AP you linked to only uses the USB connection from your computer for power.  You still need to connected your wired (ethernet) port to the AP or connect to it from your internal wireless adapter.  In my research of travel routers powered via USB, I didn't find any that provided a network device over USB to connect to the network.